# How one can calculate the following limit: $\lim_{x→∞}Ψ(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

How one can calculate the following limit:

$$\lim_{x→∞}Ψ(x)$$

where $Ψ(x)$ is the **[digamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function)** .

Comment: In the link you posted you have the fact that $\log(x)-\frac{1}{x}\leq Ψ(x)$, how is the behavior of $\log(x)-\frac{1}{x}$ at infinity?

Comment: From $\Gamma(x+1)=x\Gamma(x)$ and $\psi(x)=(\log \Gamma(x))'$ we find $\psi(x+n) = \psi(x)+\sum_{m=0}^{n-1} \frac1{x+m}$ so it is obvious that for $x \in [1,2]$, $\psi(x+n)\ge C+\sum_{m=1}^{n-1}\frac1{n-1}\ge C+\log(n-1)$